# Pasting copied data at the same row but different column with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Thorough my previous asked question, new topic is born.
Now, I am having several copied cells which I would like to paste transposed into the initial file (e.g. ThisWorkbook where the macro is located).

What I tried was to keep the same row from the block operator "FOR", to move the cursor few columns back and to paste there the selection. But an error appeared. When I use the statit way "Range("C10")" but each time the program must have different cells to paste there. So, how can I cope with that?

Thank you in advance!

```
Option Explicit

Sub FileFinder()
' Excel variables:
Dim wbResults, oWB As Workbook
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim RngS As Range
Dim sDir As String
Dim LastRow, i, Col As Long
'Optimizing CPU speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
' set the worksheet object
Col = 25
Set Sht = Worksheets("Accounts source data")
With Sht
    ' find last row with data in Column "Y" (Col = 25)
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 25).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To LastRow
        If .Cells(i, Col) = "In Scope" Then
            ' Set the range directly, no need to use `Select` and `Selection`
            Set RngS = .Cells(i, Col).Offset(, -22)
            ' Search, in same directory where the file is located, the file with that account (file comes with account number as name)
            sDir = Dir$(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & RngS.Value & ".xlsx", vbNormal)
            Set oWB = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sDir)
            oWB.Worksheets("Report").Range("B27:B30").Copy

            'My error appears here: Run-time Error 424: Object required
            'If I replace "Cells(i, Col).Offset(, -11)" from below with "Range("C10")" the code works perfectly. But this is not the desired result
            wbResults.Worksheets("Accounts source data").Cells(i, Col).Offset(, -11).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
            oWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

            ' clear objects
            Set RngS = Nothing
            Set oWB = Nothing
        End If

    Next i
End With
'End optimizing CPU speed
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to specifically use `Dim wbResults As Workbook` because `Dim wbResults, oWB As Workbook` means that `wbResults` is a `Variant`. Also you never `Set wbResults = ThisWorkbook`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick fix. Try like this:

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Accounts source data").Cells(i, Col).Offset(, -11).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True`

If it works, then try setting `wbResults` to `ThisWorkbook`, as mentioned in the comments.

---

You need to set `wbResults` to a specified workbook, as propsed in the comments. `Set wbResults = ThisWorkbook` is a possible way to do it. Furthermore, in `VBA` `Dim a,b,c as Long` sets just the last value to `Long` the other two are set to `Variant`.